# JQuery not executing defined function in .blur()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm very new to JQuery and Javascript in general, and I'm working on a project for school. While I can get everything to work without defining any functions, I want to reduce redundant code.

Here's a bit of what I'm trying to do:

```
function firstNameChanged() {
    var x = document.getElementById("firstName").value;

    if (x == null || x == "") {
        $("#firstNameError").html(" First name can't be blank!");
    }
    else {
        $("#firstNameError").html("");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){   

$("#firstName").blur(firstNameChange());
}
```

Yes I'm positive all IDs exist, because the code works when I pass it as:

```
$("#firstName").blur(function(){
    var x = document.getElementById("firstName").value;

    if (x == null || x == "") {
        $("#firstNameError").html(" First name can't be blank!");
    }
    else {
        $("#firstNameError").html("");
    }
})
```

I've looked up plenty of documentation on Javascript and JQuery syntax, debugged in Chrome, I can't figure it out.

Comment: You are calling the function, you should provide it as a callback: `$("#firstName").blur(firstNameChange);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`blur` expects a function reference as a parameter. `firstNameChange()` is *calling* the function immediately. Remove the `()`

```
$("#firstName").blur(firstNameChange);
```